# aligning 2 objects based on child objects

Tags: modeling, python

I have seen a LOT of answers to questions similar to this but havent been able to make any of them work yet.

in the pic I have a pentagon and a dodecahedron. I have placed triangles on the faces to be guides in an addon/workflow Im trying to accomplish.

I need to get the pentagon to snap to a face of the deodecahedron based on the triangles they both have as a guide, so if the triangle is bigger or angled etc., that's how it gets applied.

Currently I have:

```py
def fnRotateTo(objToRotate,objTargetVector):
    objFromVector=fnGetCenter(objToRotate.data.vertices)
    objToRotate.rotation_mode = 'QUATERNION'
    objToRotate.rotation_quaternion = objTargetVector.to_track_quat('Z','Y')
```

and that gets me close, but it's obviously not right.

I have a bunch more code to this I'm willing to share if it helps. I basically get the center/normals of the traingles and then move the parent object and rotate by the function above. The rotation is where I'm stuck.

[image]

all code so far
bl_info = {
"name": "Anchors Aweigh",
"author": "Anthony Aragues",
"version": (1, 0),
"blender": (2, 80, 0),
"location": "n > Anchors",
"description": "Create anchors on objects and use themn to snap to each other with size and scale",
"warning": "",
"doc_url": "",
"category": "Modeling",
}

```
'''
 NOTES
 # nice helpful template https://gist.github.com/tin2tin/ce4696795ad918448dfbad56668ed4d5
 # need a way of setting a primary default anchor for many to many anchor snaps
 
 # parent the anchor to the original mesh
 
 # give it special properties to use to recognize its an Anchor

        #user selects a target object
        #user selects a an object to snap to anchors on the previous object
        #user presses the button to go

        #show a list of the anchors on target object, allow select/ deselect, default apply all

        #for each anchor in target object, copy the slected object, scale and rotate to match anchor.

        #bonus, allow a collection with anchors to be used instead of a single object
        #option to create a free form anchor and put anywhere on any object
        #allow iteration without colliding objects, with optional random anchor selection
        
'''

import bpy, bmesh, mathutils
from mathutils import Vector, Matrix


def fnGetScale(arrVerts):
    objScale={"x":0,"y":0,"z":0,"center":{"x":0,"y":0,"z":0}}
    intMinX = None
    intMinY = None
    intMinZ = None
    intMaxX = None
    intMaxY = None
    intMaxZ = None
    for objVert in arrVerts:
        #coordinates per point per face of selected object
        arrCo=objVert.co.to_tuple()
        if intMinX == None or arrCo[0] < intMinX:
            intMinX=arrCo[0]
        if intMaxX == None or arrCo[0] > intMaxX:
            intMaxX=arrCo[0]
        if intMinY == None or arrCo[1] < intMinY:
            intMinY=arrCo[1]
        if intMaxY == None or arrCo[1] > intMaxY:
            intMaxY=arrCo[1]
        if intMinZ == None or arrCo[2] < intMinZ:
            intMinZ=arrCo[2]
        if intMaxZ == None or arrCo[2] > intMaxZ:
            intMaxZ=arrCo[2]
    objScale['x'] = intMaxX-intMinX
    objScale['y'] = intMaxY-intMinY
    objScale['z'] = intMaxZ-intMinZ
    return objScale

def fnGetCenter(arrVerts):
    verts_sel = [v.co for v in arrVerts]
    objCenter = sum(verts_sel, Vector()) / len(verts_sel)
    return objCenter

def fnRotateTo(objToRotate,objTargetVector):
    #Ive been using this to face a newly created item in the direction as a normal, give it a face.normal as a target
    #get vector to calc with from obj to move
    objFromVector=fnGetCenter(objToRotate.data.vertices)
    objToRotate.rotation_mode = 'QUATERNION'
    objToRotate.rotation_quaternion = objTargetVector.to_track_quat('Z','Y')
    #objToRotate.rotation_quaternion = objFromVector.to_track_quat('Z','Y').inverted() @ objTargetVector.to_track_quat('Z','Y')
    

def rotate_object(obj, loc, normal):
    up = mathutils.Vector((0, 0, 1))
    angle = normal.angle(up)
    direction = up.cross(normal)

    R = mathutils.Matrix.Rotation(angle, 4, direction)
    T = mathutils.Matrix.Translation(loc)
    M = T @ R @ T.inverted()

    obj.location = M @ obj.location
    obj.rotation_euler.rotate(M)
    
    
def fnGetFirstSelectedNormal(objMesh):
    for objFace in objMesh.faces:
        if objFace.select == True:
            return objFace.normal

def fnGetAnchor(objTarget):
    arrAnchors=[]
    for objChild in objTarget.children:
        if "anchor" in objChild:
            return objChild

def fnGetAnchors(objTarget):
    arrAnchors=[]
    for objChild in objTarget.children:
        if "anchor" in objChild:
            arrAnchors.append(objChild)
    return arrAnchors

def fnCopyObject(objSource,context):
    objNew=objSource.copy()
    objNew.data = objSource.data.copy()
    objNew.animation_data_clear()
    context.collection.objects.link(objNew)
    return objNew
    
#user input fields
class AnchorsInputs(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    #builting string (variable)property
    anchor_name: bpy.props.StringProperty(name='name')
    target_object: bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Object, name='target')
    move_object: bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Object, name='move')
    move_anchor: bpy.props.EnumProperty(name='anchor', items=[('wtf','wtf','wtf')] )
    apply_to_all: bpy.props.BoolProperty(name='copy to all anchors')

class Snap_Op(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = 'snap.go'
    bl_label = 'Move the parent objects together based on the anchors'
    
    #this is the operator function that will be called on button press
    def execute(self, context):
        if context.scene.custom_props.move_object != None:
            objMove=context.scene.custom_props.move_object
            objMoveAnchor=fnGetAnchor(objMove)                
            bpy.data.objects[objMoveAnchor.name].select_set(True)
            bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_selected()
            bpy.data.objects[objMove.name].select_set(True)
            bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CURSOR', center='MEDIAN')
            #objMove.origin_set(fnGetCenter(objMoveAnchor.data.vertices))
        if context.scene.custom_props.target_object != None:
            objTarget=context.scene.custom_props.target_object
            arrTargetAnchors=fnGetAnchors(objTarget)
            
            for objTargetAnchor in arrTargetAnchors:
                objTargetWorld=objTargetAnchor.matrix_world
                objTargetCenter=fnGetCenter(objTargetAnchor.data.vertices)
                loc = objTargetWorld @ objTargetCenter
                objNew=fnCopyObject(objMove,context)
                objNew.location=loc
                print(objNew)
                fnRotateTo(objNew,loc)
        return {'FINISHED'}

class CreateAnchor_Op(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = 'createanchor.go'
    bl_label = 'Create an Anchor for the faces selected'
    
    #this is the operator function that will be called on button press
    def execute(self, context):
        #get the scene
        objScene = context.scene
        # Get the active mesh
        obj = context.edit_object
        # Get a BMesh representation
        objMesh = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)

        #get the area between all verts selected
        arrVerts=[]
        for objVert in objMesh.verts:
            if objVert.select == True:
                arrVerts.append(objVert)
        objScale= fnGetScale(arrVerts)

        #get the normal direction of the selected faces (only need 1 face)
        objNormal = fnGetFirstSelectedNormal(objMesh)

        objCenter=fnGetCenter(arrVerts)

        bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()

        intRadius=objScale['x']/2
        if objScale['y']/2 < intRadius:
            intRadius=objScale['y']/2
        if objScale['z']/2 < intRadius:
            intRadius=objScale['z']/2

        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_circle_add(
              enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', vertices=3, fill_type='NOTHING'
            , location=(objCenter)
            , radius=1, scale=(1, 1, 1))
        objAnchor = context.active_object
        bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(intRadius/1, intRadius/1, intRadius/1), orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), 
            orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', constraint_axis=(False, True, False), mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
        objAnchor.name=objScene.custom_props.anchor_name
        objAnchor.parent=obj
        objAnchor['anchor']={"default":True}
        
        #  set the rotation the anchor in the direction of the normal
        objPointTo=obj.matrix_world @ objNormal
        fnRotateTo(objAnchor,objPointTo)

        #print(objScale)
        return {'FINISHED'}

class Anchors_Panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Anchors"
    bl_category = "Anchors"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_AnchorsPanel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        #start with first camera found
        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Create Anchors")
        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="1. Selected faces in edit mode")
        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="2. Name the Anchor")
        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="3. Run the Create script")
        row = layout.row()
        layout.prop(context.scene.custom_props, 'anchor_name')
        layout.operator("createanchor.go",text = 'Create Anchor')
        row = layout.row()
        layout.prop(context.scene.custom_props, 'target_object')
        layout.prop(context.scene.custom_props, 'apply_to_all')
        layout.prop(context.scene.custom_props, 'move_object')
        layout.prop(context.scene.custom_props, 'move_anchor')
        layout.operator("snap.go",text = 'Move and Scale')
                                
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(AnchorsInputs)
    bpy.types.Scene.custom_props = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=AnchorsInputs)
    bpy.utils.register_class(CreateAnchor_Op)
    bpy.utils.register_class(Snap_Op)
    bpy.utils.register_class(Anchors_Panel)


def unregister():
    del bpy.types.Scene.custom_props
    bpy.utils.register_class(AnchorsInputs)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(CreateAnchor_Op)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Snap_Op)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Anchors_Panel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: If this is a question about achieving this with Python, could you add 'Python' to the tags? I'm not sure whether that's what you want, so haven't done it for you.

Comment: Also recommend posting minimal working code, especially when referencing other custom methods. Suggest matching matrix world of source triangle to that target triangle.  Flipped if its a magnet type arrangement. Post more info if this is an issue.  btw @RobinBetts is a good looking rooster with hair..

Comment: added the python tag and all my code so far, thanks for looking @RobinBetts

Comment: updated, thanks @batFINGER